# Comparing things in python

Tags: python, sorting, python-3.x

I'm trying to compare things in list, tuple, etc. and I'm wondering how we specify what we want to compare. I want to sort a list: `[('A',(6,2,1,3)), ('B',(4,5,9,3)), ('C',(1,2,3,8))]` by the last number, and if the last number is equal, then sort by the 3rd number. However, I'm unsure how to approach this. I used `lambda` to sort by the last number, but when the last numbers are equal, python automatically sorts by the first number.

Answer (score 3):

Using the `lambda`, create a key which is a tuple of last number and third number:

```
mylist = [('B',(4,5,9,3)), ('C',(1,2,3,8)), ('A',(6,2,1,3))]
mylist.sort(key=lambda x:(x[1][-1], x[1][2]))
```

Outputs:

```
[('A', (6, 2, 1, 3)), ('B', (4, 5, 9, 3)), ('C', (1, 2, 3, 8))]
```

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to sort by the last element in each `tuple`, reversed.  Python translates that english to code pretty well:

```
sorted(li,key=lambda x: tuple(reversed(x[-1])))
Out[4]: [('A', (6, 2, 1, 3)), ('B', (4, 5, 9, 3)), ('C', (1, 2, 3, 8))]
```

Comment: taken literally, OP didn't actually say sort by 2nd and 1st elements, but you're *probably* right

Comment: yeah, I extrapolated a bit.

Comment: that's no reason to downvote this answer. c'mon guys! it's still perfectly valid!